# What to substitute a lost pedal dust cap with?

Tags: pedals, raleigh

I am working on my 90s Raleigh mtb (it's awesome), where one of the pedal dust caps was lost. Subsequently, the pedal without one had much more sand inside, and is in worse shape overall. As I'm finishing maintenance, I want to fix this, so, do you have any suggestions on the substitutes? My first instinct was to try a spare bar end cap, but it's much larger in diameter. Maybe I can use something small, and add a lot of plumber's tape to make it fit, but I can't think of anything right now.

Somewhere on forums people suggest coins or just no caps at all, but it doesn't sound right to me. I'll leave coins as last resort though.

Comment: You could cut a disc out of a bottle cap (normal soft drink bottle) with wire cutters and glue it in with silicone.

Answer (score 3):

By the time you have driven around town looking for a suitable sized dust cap, new Pedals might even work out cheaper.

One option could be use the pedal itself as a mold to make one from a silicon sealer.

Local hardware store will have a range of plastic end caps for things like curtain rods chair legs along with other and general hardware purposes.  You might find a suitable sized item there. Its the kind of thing an LBS might have in a box of bits.

Comment: Thanks for your useful tips. I am not very keen on buying anything new for this project, even if it costs more to sustain old stuff. Also, I've been visiting Mum yesterday and she apparently has a tube of silicon sealer, so I guess that's what I'm going with :)

Comment: Be careful though not to get silicone into the hollow where the cone is located. This will mess-up the bearing. But if you got grit and sand into the pedal body from the dust-cap side, the bearing may have suffered!

Comment: A used bicycle parts market may be a source to get a pair of old-style pedals that are whole and still be in a serviceable state. there are also new ones, especially on the fixie market, that have that old-time look and built and won't be out of place on a 90s bike.